# Managing an EventMachine Process with Capistrano

Tags: ruby, deployment, process, capistrano, eventmachine

I'm trying to deploy an EventMachine application with Capistrano. Deploying the code looks fairly easily it's how to handle the running process I'm struggling with. I want Capistrano to restart the process if it's already running, otherwise start the process.

Comment: How do you start and restart the process now?  Capistrano can essentially run any shell command that you want.

Comment: @conickal I run the program in a 'screen'. This means when I logout the program will continue running. If I want to restart the program I load the screen, terminate, run it again, then detach the screen. There's probably a much easier way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a gem called [daemon-kit](https://github.com/kennethkalmer/daemon-kit/) which easily turns a program into a daemon and handles the starting/stopping. It even has recipes for Capistrano!

Comment: That's great! daemon-kit is really slick.